# Powershell give User Input to next Step

Tags: powershell-3.0

Ibjust start to work with Powershell and found it very interesting. On my first code here i'm realy confusing :-)

```
$answer = read-host "Please Make a Selection"  
 if ($answer -eq 1){$result = Read-Host 'Enter Name for RestorePoint'}
 Checkpoint-Computer -Description $result
```

Error:

```
Checkpoint-Computer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Description'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At D:\Scripts\RestorePoint.ps1:25 char:34
+  Checkpoint-Computer -Description <<<<  $result  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Checkpoint-Computer], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CheckpointComputerCommand

Restore-Computer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RestorePoint'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At D:\Scripts\RestorePoint.ps1:27 char:32
+  Restore-Computer -RestorePoint <<<<  $RPoint  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Restore-Computer], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestoreComputerCommand
```

On the Output i'm getting some errors.

Comment: god, this indenting\formatting makes me eyes bleed

Comment: i would consider changing you code to something more reasonable, like `switch` statements instead of multiple `if`'s, and implement a do-while loop to check input, similar to following `Do { $input = Read-host "y or n" } while (('y','n') -notcontains $input)`